# After creating an accordion, there is a random blue border on top of the text panel. I used the code from foundation.zurb. How do I get rid of this?

Tags: accordion, zurb-foundation

After creating an accordion, there is a random blue border on top of the text panel. I used the code from *foundation.zurb*.  How do I get rid of this?

Here is the code from *foundation.zurb* that I used.

```html
<ul class="accordion">
  <li class="active">
    <div class="title">
      <h5>Accordion Panel 1</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="title">
      <h5>Accordion Panel 2</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="title">
      <h5>Accordion Panel 3</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the looks of your code you are using F3 (version 3). If so then that is the intended behavior and actually that is not random. So if you click on each tab (each accordion) you will see a blue border on top of each accordion. You can turn it off by overriding the style:

```
ul.accordion > li.active {
    border-top: medium none !important;
}
```